# error 503 localhost google datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty, google-cloud-datastore

So I am a total novice when it comes to datastore and cloud interaction, and I am trying to figure out the basics of datastore through the google bookshelf tutorial. I have the free trial running for 60 days and just want to wrap my head around how it works.

So in the setup I reached this portion of the tutorial ([screenshot of google site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDXX4.png)) (this is the url: https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-forms) and I seem to be doing okay. I ran the code it asks for and seem to have started a jetty server in my terminal. It reads:

> [INFO] Started ServerConnector@5ef8c2f7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
>   [INFO] Started @14439ms
>   [INFO] Started Jetty Server

So the next step is to go to localhost8080 in my browser but when I get there I get an HTTP 503 Error that reads:

> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>   Service Unavailable

I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere, so I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight into what I should do. Thanks!